# Where did printer driver settings go on a Canon IP 3100?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, printing, canon

I have had my Canon IP 3100 printer for years, and with every version of Ubuntu, since around 8 or so, it has been auto detected and worked perfectly.

Now, with Ubuntu 11.10, it has been detected as some kind of "generic text only printer", and I can't even print a test page.

I've looked at the printer interface, and there doesn't seem to be any way at all to manually select the right printer driver.

This is all there is in the printer dialogue in the settings manager:

[image: printer dialog]

The only place to go is "Options", but if you do that, all you get is this:

[image: printer options]

Not much to go on.

I have also tried removing it and reinstalling it, but that has not helped.

How do I get my printer drivers back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution seemed to be a two part thing. One was following the instructions here.

It didn't work at first, though. Part of the key seems to be to not try and install the drivers using the interface above, but instead close that, turn the printer on, and use the dialog that comes up when the printer first connects.

Anyway... had to go back to the command line in 11.10. Not a step forward IMHO. But at least the printer is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Click this: http://localhost:631

I had a same problem. But now solved. I also use Ubuntu 11.10(amd64) and Canon iP-3100.